# How to open and modify .gtk plugin

Tags: dm-script

I have found a plugin (EELSTools.gtk from http://www.dmscripting.com) which I want to modify.

The plugin contains nearly every function I need, but I want also to integrate some extra functions.

Does anyone know how to open `.gtk` files?

Answer (score 0):

### You can't and shouldn't.

*.gtk files are packages files with the *purpose* of encapsulation. This might either be because of convenience, but it might as well be, because the author does not want to make the code open-source. (Note that there are some proprietory plugins as well, they are also .gtk files.)

If you have found a plugin and want to expand on it, the best way forward is to contact the plugin-author.

Answer (score 0):

The *.gtk files get loaded before *.s files.  If you install your own script from DM Menu Install Script File or Install Script, you can add it to the menu that the *.gtk file has, e.g. EELSTools.  It is added at the end of the list.  For example, I put a measure ZLP width script in EELSTools.